# Rails migration to change column type from text to json (Postgresql)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, rails-migrations

I've been trying unsuccessfully to change a column type in my Postgres database from text to json. Here's what I've tried...

```
class ChangeNotesTypeInPlaces < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def up
    execute 'ALTER TABLE places ALTER COLUMN notes TYPE json USING (notes::json)'
  end

  def down
    execute 'ALTER TABLE places ALTER COLUMN notes TYPE text USING (notes::text)'
  end
end
```

Also...

```
class ChangeNotesTypeInPlaces < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def up
    change_column :places, :notes, 'json USING CAST(notes AS json)'
  end

  def down
    change_column :places, :notes, 'text USING CAST(notes AS text)'
  end
end
```

Both of these return the same error...

```
PG::InvalidTextRepresentation: ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type json
```

Comment: Are the `notes` column already had a value that is not a valid json?

Comment: That's a good question. I've never saved data in this column (in development, not the same case in production unfortunately), but I also don't have a not-null constraint on that column. Could it be that it has been saving an empty string into that column which is causing this? If yes, do you know how I can get around this?

Comment: If you don't have the not-null constraint, then null value would be just fine or you could just save empty json `{}`. It is not accepting empty string.

Answer (score 13):

Using Rails 5.1.x and PostgreSQL 9.4, here is what worked for me when converting text columns (containing valid json) to jsonb columns :

```
class ChangeTextColumnsToJson < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    change_column :table_name, :column_name, :jsonb, using: 'column_name::text::jsonb'
  end
end
```

Comment: This worked in postgres 9.6 rails 5.1, i had to add the reverse:


def down
    change_column :table_name, :column_name, :text
end

Comment: this same solution works for AR::Migration[6.1], as always, make sure the data is valid, otherwise advise add column, copy data rename column

Answer (score 2):

I was able to accomplish it using:

```
def change
  change_column :places, :notes, :json, using: 'notes::JSON'
end
```

This won't be reversible though; I imagine you can split it out into separate up and down definitions, but I didn't feel the need to.

Comment: Should separate `up` and `down`.

Answer (score 0):

I just solved a similar problem. Trying to adapt it for your question, it would look (mostly?) like this.

```
class ChangeNotesTypeInPlaces < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def up
    change_column :places, :notes, :jsonb, using: 'CAST(value AS JSON)'
  end

  def down
    change_column :places, :notes, :text
  end
end
```

Comment: works for me if the word 'value' in the CAST is replaced with 'notes'