# SQL statement to convert jsonb hash to json string

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, json, postgresql, jsonb

I have a rails data migration (postgres db) where I have to use pure sql to convert the data due to some model restrictions. The data is stored as json as a string, but I need it to be a usable hash for other purposes.

My migration works to convert it to the hash. However, my down method ends up just deleting the data or leaving it as an empty {}. Btw to clear up any confusion, my column name is actually saved as `data` in table `Games`

Based on my up method, how would i properly reverse the migration using sql only?

```
class ConvertGamesDataToJson < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def up
    statement = <<~SQL
      update games set data = regexp_replace(trim(both '"' from data::text), '\\\\"', '"', 'g')::jsonb;
    SQL

    ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(statement)
    # this part works!
  end

  def down
    statement = <<~SQL
      update games set data = to_json(data::text)::jsonb;
    SQL

    ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(statement)
  end
end
```

Here is how the it looks after properly converting it

```
data: {
  "id"=>"d092a-f2323",
  "recent"=>'yes',
  "note"=>"some text",
  "order"=>1
}
```

how it is before the migration and what it needs to rollback to:

```
data: 
  "{
    \"id\":\"d092a-f2323\",
    \"recent\":\"yes\",
    \"note\":\"some text\",
    \"order\":1,
  }"
```

Comment: Can you show the schema for `games`, please? And please show a sample of the data in question. If it is truly JSON you should be able to just change the column type: `alter table games alter column data type jsonb USING data::jsonb;` Can you explain what "*Btw to clear up any confusion, my column name is actually saved as data in table Games*" means? I wasn't confused before, now I am. :)

Comment: Are you sure those `\"` escapes are really there and not just an artifact of how it's displayed? Try using `puts`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're displaying a data structure in the rails console, those `\"` aren't really there. They're just formatting because the console has wrapped the string in `"`. For example...

```
[2] pry(main)> %{"up": "down"}
=> "\"up\": \"down\""
```

But if we print it...

```
[3] pry(main)> puts %{"up": "down"}
"up": "down"
```

Given that is a JSON string, you can simply change the type of the column to jsonb and be done with it.

```
-- up
alter table games alter column data type jsonb USING data::jsonb;

-- down
alter table games alter column data type text;
```

Postgres doesn't know how to automatically cast text to jsonb, so we need to tell it. `using data::jsonb` does a simple cast of the text to jsonb. It can cast jsonb to text just fine.

[You can do this in a migration with `change_column`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48854807/14660).

```
def up
  change_column :users, :data, :jsonb, using: 'data::jsonb'
end

def down
  change_column :users, :data, :text
end
```

Comment: I'm doing exactly that an somehow the migration seems to be converting the data to a Ruby hash. ```PG::InvalidTextRepresentation: ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type json; DETAIL:  Token "=" is invalid.; CONTEXT:  JSON data, line 1: {"first_name"=...```

Comment: @Daniel "*The data is stored as json as a string*" I expect you actually stored it as a Ruby Hash. You will have to convert the existing data to JSON, then migrate the column to jsonb.

Comment: Yep, a few entities had a Ruby hash stored from an erroneous import  Converting them to JSON fixed it.